# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, url, relative-path, filepath

So, I have a little problem on set path when I already hosting all the file.

This is my code :

```
$baseDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once $baseDir.'/task_manager/include/CardStoreDB.php';
```

When I try all the file on localhost, everything going well.

But, when I hosting all the file, I got error like this in `index.php`   :

```
Warning: require_once(/home/u458066278/public_html/bawakartu/task_manager/include/CardStoreDB.php)
```

This is the folder structure :

```
 - bawakartu
   |- task_manager
     |- include
       |+ CardStoreDB.php
     |- v1
       |+ index.php
```

Am I doing something wrong ?
I got little frustrated because all the files works fine when I try on localhost..

**Note : All the files works fine when I try it on localhost, but when I copy and paste all the files to hosting. I got that error**

Comment: Are your files and folder equal? Linux servers are case-sensitive, Windows is not.

Comment: yes all files name and folder are same

Comment: your folder 'include' is really 'Include' is it?

Comment: @fortune : yep It is really include, I do not change anything, I just copy and pasted all the files from localhost to hosting.

Comment: but your folder structure showing include in Include. I mean capital 'I'

Comment: Try a `var_dump(scan_dir(#baseDir));` to see which dir loads.

Comment: I got Call to undefined function scan_dir()  @Mouser

Comment: sorry underscore too much `scandir` is the correct function call